# Error en SQLite: "attempt to write a readonly database"

Tags: c#, sqlite

Todas las consultas me funcionan bien pero cuando intento hacer un `insert` en SQLite me marca el siguiente error:

> attempt to write a readonly database

Comment: Mira esta [guia](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Si no das mas informacion respecto de lo que pasa, no vamos a poder ayudarte, el error dice que la base es de solo lectura.

Comment: ¿En qué lugar has guardado la base de datos? ¿Tienes permiso de escritura en ese lugar? ¿Has probado ejecutar tu aplicación como administrador?

Comment: Que version de sqlite utilizar?

Comment: Ese error casi siempre vienen provocado porque el archivo de la base de datos se encuentra en una carpeta donde la aplicación no tiene permisos.

Comment: Puede que entres en la BBDD con un usuario que no tenga permisos de insercion o que estes intentando insertar en un tabla que no tengas permisos. O como ha dicho @Pikoh que el archivo de la base de datos esta en una carpeta en la que la aplicacion no tenga permisos.

Answer (score 1):

## Ya lo solucioné

El error era provocado porque mi base de datos era .SQLite y la solución fue cambiarla a .db
Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Excelente, date una vuelta por https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour así conocerás mayores detalles del sitio :D Bienvenido bro!

Answer (score 0):

Parece que el problema que tienes es que creas la base de datos sin seguridad, entonces al intentar conectarte a ella no te deja.

Deberías indicar una contraseña a la hora de crear la base de datos y en la cadena de conexión indicar la contraseña:

```
SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection("DataSource=MyDatabase.sqlite;Version=3;");
conn.SetPassword("password");
conn.open();
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda.